dropdown list is implemented using a custom UI library or framework, which leads to an obscuring issue

// Function to select the first option from a dropdown
def selectFirstOptionFromDropdown(Object dropdownObject) {
    WebUI.click(dropdownObject)
    /* WebUI.executeJavaScript()
    //javascript
    var dropdownContainer = document.querySelector('.dropdown-container'); 
    var firstListItem = dropdownContainer.querySelector('li');
    firstListItem.click(); */
    WebDriver driver = DriverFactory.getWebDriver()
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
    List<WebElement> options = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div/ul/li")))
    //WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/form/div/div/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]/div")))
    //element.click()
    options.get(1).click()
}

It's supposed to select the values and then move on to the next and keep executing. But it selects the value from the dropdown list and it appears for a brief moment before it gets obscured. not sure why it keeps happening but it prevents it from moving on.
